# Error in returning spark rdd from a function called inside the map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have a collection of rowkeys (plants as shown below) from hbase table and I want to make a fetchData function which returns rdd data for rowkeys from the collection. Goal is to get union of RDDs from fetchData method for each element from plants collection. I have given the relevant part of code below. My issue is, the code is giving compilation error for return type of fetchData:

> println("PartB: "+ hBaseRDD.getNumPartitions)
>
> error: value getNumPartitions is not a member of Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[it.nerdammer.spark.test.sys.Record]]

I am using scala 2.11.8 spark 2.2.0 and maven compilation

```
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object sys {
  case class systems( rowkey: String, iacp: Option[String], temp: Option[String])

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("myApp").config("spark.executor.cores",4).getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  type Record = (String, Option[String], Option[String])

  def fetchData(plant: String): RDD[Record] = {
    val start_index = plant
    val end_index = plant + "z"
    //The below command works fine if I run it in main function, but to get multiple rows from hbase, I am using it in a separate function
    spark.sparkContext.hbaseTable[Record]("test_table").select("iacp","temp").inColumnFamily("pp").withStartRow(start_index).withStopRow(end_index)

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //the below elements in the collection are prefix of relevant rowkeys in hbase table ("test_table") 
    val plants = Vector("a8","cu","aw","fx")
    val hBaseRDD = plants.map( pp => fetchData(pp))
    println("Part: "+ hBaseRDD.getNumPartitions)
    /*
      rest of the code
    */
  }

}
```

Here is the working version of code. The problem here is that I am using for loop and I have to request data corresponding to rowkey (plants) vector from HBase in each loop instead of getting all the data first and then executing rest of the codes

```
    import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    object sys {
      case class systems( rowkey: String, iacp: Option[String], temp: Option[String])
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("myApp").config("spark.executor.cores",4).getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

        type Record = (String, Option[String], Option[String])
        val plants = Vector("a8","cu","aw","fx")
        
        for (plant <- plants){
          val start_index = plant
          val end_index = plant + "z"
          val hBaseRDD = spark.sparkContext.hbaseTable[Record]("test_table").select("iacp","temp").inColumnFamily("pp").withStartRow(start_index).withStopRow(end_index)
          println("Part: "+ hBaseRDD.getNumPartitions)
          /*
            rest of the code
          */
        }
      }
    }
```

After trying, this is where I am stuck now. So how can I cast the type to required.

```
scala>   def fetchData(plant: String) = {
     |     val start_index = plant
     |     val end_index = plant + "~"
     |     val x1 = spark.sparkContext.hbaseTable[Record]("test_table").select("iacp","temp").inColumnFamily("pp").withStartRow(start_index).withStopRow(end_index)
     |     x1
     |   }
```

Define the function in REPL and running it

```
scala> val hBaseRDD = plants.map( pp => fetchData(pp)).reduceOption(_ union _)
<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Option[String], Option[String])]
 required: it.nerdammer.spark.hbase.HBaseReaderBuilder[(String, Option[String], Option[String])]
       val hBaseRDD = plants.map( pp => fetchData(pp)).reduceOption(_ union _)
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The message tells u the answer, surely.

Comment: I am asking because the message is not clear to me. So, I don't see the point for giving negative vote, if you don't want to answer.
I have tried changing return type of fetchData function but couldn't resolve the error.
Anyways, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well i did not give the min1. But the msg is clear I think.

Comment: Will look later.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the working version, which uses for loop.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `hBaseRDD` is `Vector[_]` and not `RDD[_]`, so you can't execute method `getNumPartitions` on it. If I understand correctly you want to union fetched RDDs. You can do it by `plants.map( pp => fetchData(pp)).reduceOption(_ union _)` (I recommend to use `reduceOption` because it won't fail on empty list, but you can use `reduce` if you confident that list is not empty)

Also the returned type of `fetchData` is `RDD[U]`, but I didn't find any definition of `U`. Probably this is the reason why compiler infer `Vector[Nothing]` instead of `Vector[RDD[Record]]`. In order to avoid subsequent errors you should also change `RDD[U]` to `RDD[Record]`.

Comment: Yes, I want the union of fetchedData RDDs. I have edited my question to include the working version of the code. In the working version, hBaseRDD.getNumPartitions method gives me the partition of RDD. I tried changing the return type to fetchData to Vector[RDD[Record]] or using the plants.map( pp => fetchData(pp)).reduceOption(_ union _) approach but they did not work

Comment: I have updated the question towards the end. Now, I am using reduceOption function. I think I am very close to solution, please let me know if you can help resolve the issue.
Thanks